# how to use manage.py inexplicitely

Tags: python, django, unix, terminal

so when I'm im in my root directory (where `manage.py` lives), if I do `manage.py runserver` it says `command not found`. I have to do `~/<project_name>/manage.py runserver` for it to work. Why is this?

Comment: That is now the command line works... you have to specify the path to the script you want to execute. You can however do `./manage.py runserver` from the project root.

Comment: When I ran the project off line I only had to write `python manage.py runserver` any idea why?

Comment: There is a difference between `python manage.py runserver` and `manage.py runserver` which is what you have in your question. The first will work, but if you don't want to call `python` then you have to explicitly provide the path to the script.

Answer (score -1):

In `manage.py runserver`, the `manage.py` is only a file, not a command! You can not do this since the Linux(shell) could only execute binary executable image.

If you want to run `manage.py` without python, you could add (supposed that you used Linux)

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

at the head of `manage.py`, and make it executable with `chmod +x manage.py`.

And now, you could run `./manage.py runserver`

Answer (score -1):

You can add manage.py to your bash as a alias to easily access it.
Add

```
alias <key>=“~/<project_name>/manage.py runserver”
```

Add it to ~/.bashrc file (create if doesn’t exists

Replace key with code you prefer like `mnrun` and rerun bash and type mnrun